# django - cant pass selected tag into js (ajax code)

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, onclick, html-select

My selection.html:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="loadDoc2()" value="continue" style="height:50px;">

<select style="direction: rtl;width:200px;height:50px;">
    {% for item in items %}
        <option class="shahr-options" value="{{ item.shahr }}"> {{ item.shahr }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

And this is script2.js:

```
function loadDoc2(shahr) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/boxes=" + shahr, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

How I can pass the user choise into `onclick="loadDoc2()"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```js
function loadDoc2(value) {
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="loadDoc2(document.getElementById('shahr-select').value)" value="continue" style="height:50px;">

<select id="shahr-select" style="direction: rtl;width:200px;height:50px;">
  <option class="shahr-options" value="1">first</option>
  <option class="shahr-options" value="2">second</option>
  <option class="shahr-options" value="3">third</option>
</select>
```

the .value on a select will get the selected value

Comment: It does not work, when I click the continue button, nothing happens.

Comment: I don't know was you have in your function `loadDoc2` so I assumed it would be ok, I edited my answer to put a working example.

Comment: Thank you @user3, but it still not working for me, maybe I have not explained good or enough, so let me edit my question right now.

Comment: maybe this part `onclick="loadDoc2(document.getElementById('shahr-select').value)"` does not working well for me.

Comment: @niloofar Maybe it's the `document.getElementById('shahr-select')` part that cannot find your select, did you add the `id="shahr-select"` to the `<select>` ?

Comment: did you try to log the shahr parameter in your function to see if the problem comes from the value or the rest ? Also maybe it's a browser problem, because it's working for me in chrome & IE, what version do you have ?

Comment: For example this works `<input type="submit" onclick="loadDoc2('isf')" value="ادامه" style="height:50px;">` . firefox.

Comment: I tried your code again, It's working with your alert code but not with my ajax function. Look at script2.js, I just changes those two "shahr" words with "value" but It does not work. When I click the button ajax does not work.